# nodejs + shell(expect) +child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, child-process

i have a small problem in creating javascript.

i have a js which spawn shell script(expect, which ssh another computer, and send some data back to nodejs.

i have problem in multithreading.

```
var cons = spawn('./somescript');
var content;
cons.stdout.on('data', function(block)
{
content += block;
mrdialist = JSON.parse(block);
....
console.log("" + block);
});
console.log("hjdfsdf");
here is some actions with loaded and parced data.
```

but when i try to execute jscript, it start from the  beginning, and make all actions through loading data without loading and parsing,
how can i continue execution of the code onlu, after execution

```
    console.log("" + block);
    });
    console.log("hjdfsdf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spawn will be execute asynchrounsly. you have to execute your code when event `close` will be emit.

```
var cons = spawn('./somescript');
var content;
cons.stdout.on('data', function(block)
{
content += block;
mrdialist = JSON.parse(block);
....
console.log("" + block);
});

cons.on('close', function () {
    console.log("hjdfsdf");
    // manipulate content
    console.log("content", content);
});
```

Comment: this is a question how to do it

Comment: it still continue executing whole script, even after imolementing on ('close')

Comment: yes. any code after will be executed directly without waiting for spawn to execute. You can't make synchronous process_child so you have to put all the code you want to execute after the spawn inside the function connected on "close" event.

Comment: but what i have to do, if there is not the only task on that script?
if i have several tasks in requesting ssh answer?

Comment: you have to put all your task on the close event. you can split in many function as you cal call `on` function many time. but take care to avoid callback hell http://callbackhell.com/